# perl,mysql table name limit?

Tags: mysql, perl

i am interacting with the mysql database via perl. I was wondering if there are table name limits.

Also. How do i handle special characters within the table names when creating it through perl?

thanks

Comment: Yes! I am using the DBI package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html), the maximum length for a table name is 64 characters. This  page also describes the permissible syntax for identifiers.